# Mongo Query: How to get the last_activity for an user using aggregate

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongo aggregate,

My requirement is to show `user` and his `last_activity_time` and `last_activity`.

```
Collection Object:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123456"),
    "activity_count" : NumberLong(0),
    "dt" : ISODate("2014-02-18T20:45:00.001Z"),
    "job_functions" : [ ],
    "joined_time" : ISODate("2014-01-27T22:53:57.024Z"),
    "views_cnt" : NumberLong(6),
    "last_activity" : "Login",
    "last_activity_time" : ISODate("2014-02-18T20:56:43.552Z"),
    "locations" : [ ],
    "user_id" : "123456",
    "user_name" : "User 1"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("789034"),
    "activity_count" : NumberLong(0),
    "dt" : ISODate("2014-02-18T21:45:00.001Z"),
    "job_functions" : [ ],
    "joined_time" : ISODate("2014-01-27T22:53:57.024Z"),
    "views_cnt" : NumberLong(6),
    "last_activity" : "Page View",
    "last_activity_time" : ISODate("2014-02-18T20:56:43.552Z"),
    "locations" : [ ],
    "user_id" : "123456",
    "user_name" : "User 1"
}
```

I need to get

```
{
_id: {
    user_id: "123456"
},
    key: "123456",
    user_name: "Ba Pub",
    last_activity_time: "2014-02-18T20:56:43.552Z",
    joined_time: "2014-01-27T22:53:57.024Z",
    last_activity: "Page View"
}
```

the problem I am facing is `last_activity_time`, I can get `max(last_activity_time)`, but last_activity is bit tricky.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a $sort phase in the aggregation pipeline (prior to the group phase) to sort by `last_activity_time` descending and then use the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator to get the `last_activity`

Comment: My Final output should be top active users, that is based on **activity_count**

Comment: This is the aggregate query I have come up with,

Comment: Glad to be of help.  If the answer helped, you should consider accepting/upvoting it :)

Answer (score 0):

db.r_user.aggregate({
    "$match":{"dt":{"$gte":ISODate("2013-12-12T18:30:00.000Z"), "$lte":ISODate("2014-03-19T18:29:59.999Z")}}},
    {"$match":{"activity_count":{"$gt":0}}},
    {"$project":{"u":1,"user_id":1,"user_name":1,"last_activity_time":1,"job_functions":1,"locations":1, 
        "joined_time":1,"first_visit_time":1,"activity_count":1,"last_activity":1, "dt":1}},
    {"$sort":{"last_activity_time":-1}},
    {"$group": {"_id":{"user_id":"$user_id"}, "key":{"$first":"$user_id"},"user_name":{"$first":"$user_name"}, 
        "last_activity_time":{"$max":"$last_activity_time"},"job_functions":{"$last":"$job_functions"}, 
        "locations":{"$last":"$locations"},"joined_time":{"$last":"$joined_time"}, 
        "first_visit_time":{"$min":"$first_visit_time"},"activity_count":{"$sum":"$activity_count"}, 
        "last_activity":{"$first":"$last_activity"}} }, 
        {"$sort":{"activity_count":-1,"_id":1}}, {"$skip":5},{"$limit":5}

Comment: This is my aggregate query, the final output is top 5 active users **active_count**, in that top 5 I need to get the last activity of that user.